# On The Subject of Bitmaps

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Bitmaps

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... A 26x26 grid... *26*... Why does that number ring a bell?! ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The image at the top is

> the XOR of the circles below, each suitably offset.

If we

> label the "pixels" A-Z from top to bottom, and then A-Z from left to right, and read off the y-then-x of the circles' centres, starting with the largest,

we get

> PLEASE GUESS REGISTERED OWNER.

At this point I thought there was more to do, but Deusovi informs me in comments that

> this isn't an instruction to figure out the "registered owner" of some particular thing (e.g., the trademark to a logo that resembles the original bitmap); rather, the answer *is* the words REGISTERED OWNER.

The following diagrams may or may not clarify things a bit.

> [image]

and

> [image]

Here

> the circles are numbered from smallest to largest, which turns out to be the wrong order. Also, #7 is clipped at the top because it was only part-way through the solving process that I realised it would be helpful to work with an image with some extra "margin" on all sides.

Comment: This isn't 'partial' -- the two-word phrase that the puzzle is telling you to guess is the answer!

Comment: Oh! Fair enough, then. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: (The first part of the message was intended to confirm that it *was* the answer rather than a thing you needed to look up -- as well as getting the letter count to work out.)